# Fixed icon in scrollable div

Tags: css

I know that fixed positioning does not work relative to the parent, only to the browser window and the solution is absolute, but I also have a problem with that.

In the div in which I need a scroll inside, I have to put the icon always visible in the bottom right corner.

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nck7o0jL/

Below is my code.

```css
        .big {
            height: 600px;
            width: 600px;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }

        .small {
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            border: 2px solid red;
            overflow: auto;
            position: relative;
            resize: both;
        }

        img {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 15px;
            bottom: 15px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="small"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-close-circled-128.png">
        <div class="big">
        </div>


    </div>
```

As you can see, by stretching the div.small the icon is held, but during the scroll it is not.

Will someone give a helping hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approximate this using flexbox and position:sticky

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.big {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.small {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: auto 0 15px auto;
  position: sticky;
  order: 1;
  right: 15px;
  top: calc(100% - 45px);
}
```

```html
<div class="small"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-close-circled-128.png">
  <div class="big">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One more thing,

there is a problem if I want to add more icons. With the horizontal scroll div, the icons behave correctly, but if you start to stretch the div to the right (over 600px + icon size), they stop sticking. Because of display flex, they start to occupy the space proportionally and img {flex-shrink: 0} doesn't work.

I tried to do it like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/km6vwgo9/

Do you have an idea how to prevent this?

Comment: @Thomas the auto margin on the left should be added to only the first image and it will push all the other to the right: https://jsfiddle.net/vt2867n5/

Comment: I was able to solve this by giving an additional container for icons :) -> https://jsfiddle.net/km6vwgo9/1/

Comment: even better so you apply sticky in one place ;)

Comment: do you have an idea how to add another div (e.g. with text) to div.small so that its width matches the width of div.small? The only chance for a new div to appear is position absolute (does not work "sticky"), but this in turn sets its width to the browser window, not the parent that is resize: both. Here's the problem -> https://jsfiddle.net/ah652mg8/ So, do you have an idea that the yellow div should fit into div.small and stretch with it?